# Adding language in URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, translation, browser-history, disqus

I'm creating a single-page site, and I came across a problem that I can not solve. I have my menu with "Home | Blog | Contact" etc, change the URL with the javascript without updating the page with the code below:

```
window.history.replaceState({url: stgUrl}, "", stgUrl);
```

so I can see that the URL is modified correctly, the problem is that my site is in two different languages, and I want to put something like "/pt/" e "/en/" so the user can better visualize what language is browsing. The problem is that when I do this:

```
window.history.replaceState({url: stgUrl}, "", '/en'+stgUrl);
```

I get file upload errors, such as site images(Get 404: Not Found), which are not finding the path correctly anymore, because of '/en'.

since the changed url looks like this: **mysite.com/en/**

I would also like to add comments to blog posts on the site, and I saw that to add Disqus comments, I would need to have different urls for each post, so I can better control the comments, it's also something I do not know how to do.

*obs: my site will be hosted without access to a server, so everything should work on the client, like a static but one page blog.*

And how do I update the page with the url changed without receiving a 404? I would like to go to the home page for example, or update and maintain the current page.

**So my question about urls comes down to three questions:**

**1 -** How to change the url with "/pt" and "/en" and not receive 404 for images not found?

**2 -** How to change the url in order to generate comments from Disqus?

**3 -** How to update the page with the url changed without receiving a 404?

Comment: A URL is a resource location. If you add an `pt` to the location, you have to organize your files, that they can be located in the `pt` location.

Comment: @ceving but the way I translate the site is dynamically with javascript, there are not two files, one for each language, it's just one.

Comment: If you have just one location it is an error to define two different URLs. And the number for this error is 404.

Comment: @ceving that's right, and what about Disqus' comments, how could I do it? "mysite.com/blog_post155445" for example, since then could not do "mysite.com/blog/post155445" because there is no blog directory in my project with the posts, the posts are strigs and they are all in one file only , which is generated by a generator in nodejs.